# Flask.url_for() error: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed

Tags: flask

I have a trivial app where I'm trying to redirect the favicon per:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/favicon/

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/favicon.ico', redirect_to=flask.url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))
```

But this fails with:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.
```

So, guessing, I try this:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    flask.current_app.add_url_rule('/favicon.ico', redirect_to=flask.url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))
```

But get a different error:

```
RuntimeError: Application was not able to create a URL adapter for request independent URL generation. You might be able to fix this by setting the SERVER_NAME config variable.
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/?highlight=server_name#SERVER_NAME):

> Setting a SERVER_NAME also by default enables URL generation without a request context but with an application context.

since you're using `app_context`, you may set the `SERVER_NAME` Configuration Value.

By the way, as the [doc:Adding a favicon](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/?highlight=favicon) says:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
```

the above line should be enough for most browsers, we don't have to do any other things.

Comment: What if I would like to have a favicon without html template rendering? Let's say, on the classic "hello world" example.

Comment: The docs also suggest adding the `app.add_url_rule` as per the question for account for older browsers

Answer (score 9):

Late answer, I've just run into the same problem. I don't see a big downside in handling the redirect like this instead:

```python
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))
```

This prevents url_for from being called before the application is ready.

To give a counterpoint to using a link in the HTML only, it's a good practice for every site to have a favicon.ico and robots.txt at the root level - even if they're empty. It avoids problems [like this](https://blog.nearlyfreespeech.net/2009/06/16/quick-wordpress-performance-tip-create-a-favicon/#more-94) and other unnecessary errors that adds noise to logs.

Comment: The [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/) suggest using `send_from_directory` rather than `redirect`

Answer (score 3):

Don't put this in the app but in the html file

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width/2, initial-scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    </head>
```

Comment: Good answer, except OP is looking for a favicon: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: The linked doc article covers exactly why it might be necessary to add such a redirect nonetheless.