# Using url_for while streaming template from Flask raises RunTimeError

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am rendering a template by streaming data from a Flask view. When I do not use `url_for`, the page works correctly. If I add `url_for`, I get `RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.`

I tried the answer in [Flask.url_for() error: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766082/flask-url-for-error-attempted-to-generate-a-url-without-the-application-conte), but I still get the error after adding `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost:5000'`

How can I generate urls in the streamed template, preferably without setting `SERVER_NAME` or hardcoding the path?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.png') }}">
</head>
<body>
    {% for number in data %}
    <script>
        console.log(JSON.parse({{ number|tojson }}));
    </script>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import Flask, json

app = Flask(__name__)

def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv

@app.route('/')
def main():
    def generate():
        for number in range(10):
            yield json.dumps(number)

    return Response(stream_template('index.html', data=generate()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552644/4073934