# RuntimeError when trying to serve favicon with Flask

Tags: python, flask, favicon

I followed the instructions for serving favicons from [Flask's docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/), and added the line `app.add_url_rule('/favicon.ico', redirect_to=url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))` to my server. But when I run it I get this error:

```
  File "server.py", line X, in __init__
    redirect_to=url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))
  File "/python3.9/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 306, in url_for
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.
```

I am using a class-based server, with the basics reproduced here:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        # Set up routes:
        self.app.route("/")(self.index)

        # Error occurs here:
        self.app.add_url_rule('/favicon.ico',
                         redirect_to=url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))
        
        self.app.register_error_handler(HTTPException, self.handle_http_error)

    def index(self):
        return render_template("index.html")

    @staticmethod
    def error(msg):
        """Custom error handler"""
        return render_template("error.html", msg=msg)

    def handle_http_error(self, e):
        return self.error(f"{e.code} {e.name}: {e.description}"), e.code

    def start(self):
        self.app.run(host=self.host, port=self.port)


server = Server("localhost", 8080)
server.start()
```

My guess is I put the line to serve the favicon in the wrong spot. The error message says `This has to be executed when application context is available.`, but I'm not sure exactly what that means. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766082/flask-url-for-error-attempted-to-generate-a-url-without-the-application-conte) but the answer is a bit vague, and I couldn't figure out how to incorporate it into my code. Also, that user had a `with` statement, which I tried but couldn't get to work. I tried adding a `SERVER_NAME` config variable but it didn't change anything (I also had no idea what to put in it, so that's probably another issue).

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766082/flask-url-for-error-attempted-to-generate-a-url-without-the-application-conte) that may be of interest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask.url\_for() error: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766082/flask-url-for-error-attempted-to-generate-a-url-without-the-application-conte)

Comment: Couldn't get those answers and a `with` statement to work, I'm probably not implementing them right.